# SQL - Get average count GROUP BY months

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
Ticket |date_created       |date_removed

ticket1|2015-05-14 15:08:65|2015-05-11 10:50:11
```

I'm trying to find the average count of date_removed minus date_created, and then group by months.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select AVG(DATEDIFF(day, date_created, date_resolved)) AS 'avg_days' from 
my_table
```

gives me the avg number of days for the entire query. 
How would I go about grouping by months as well?

I've tried the following:

```
select AVG(DATEDIFF(day, date_created, date_resolved)) AS 'avg_days', 
MONTH(date_created) AS 'month' from my_table
```

but got the error:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a `GROUP BY` clause and MySQL's [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) (with latter date first) does not take unit parameter like *day* which you may be confusing different RDBMS methods like SQL Server.

```
select MONTH(date_created) AS 'month',
       AVG(DATEDIFF(date_resolved, date_created)) AS 'avg_days', 
from my_table
group by MONTH(date_created);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to convert to date format instead of work with datetime?

```
select AVG(DATEDIFF(day, convert(date,date_created,102),convert(date,date_removed,102)) )
from table
```